# How to stop binding service when app is killed from recent apps in Android 10

Tags: android

I have a service which I start in `onCreate` method with

```
val service = Intent(this,Service::class.java)
startService(service)
bindService(service, ServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

and I unbind from it in `onStop`. Service is responsible for updating current location. In it, on `onCreate` method, I start location updates with looper from newly created ThreadHandler(created in service).

```
val newThread = HandlerThread("LocationUpdatesThread")
newThread.start()
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    1000,
    1f,
    locationListener, newThread.looper)
```

Problem I have is, that this service is not stopped or at least some background process is left hanging when application is killed from recent apps. To this conclusion I got because I'm using Pusher in main activity to listen for online status of users, but when i kill an app, user is not unsubscribed from channel - meaning app is not closed properly. Also, if I don't start service at all, everything works fine, so that's why I think the problem is with the service. Twist is that this occurs **ONLY in API 29** ( Android 10). On APIs below everything works fine - meaning service is being kill as it should. I have set in android manifest service tag `stopwithtask="true"` that handles killing of service. Does anyone have some idea why is this happening or what am I missing?

Comment: Where is `newThread` `join()-ed`, and where is your call to `removeUpdates()`? Please add this code to your question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm removing updates in `onDestroy` method. As for joining, I never did `join()`. There never were problems with this in api's < 29 so I assume HandlerThread is lasting as long as service does. @greeble31

Comment: So, I assume you "unsubscribe from the channel" in `Service.onDestroy()`, as well? And you have verified that `onDestroy()` is not being called in API 29, and neither is the app crashing?

Comment: Pusher is automatically unsubscribing and closing connections when application closes, so there is no unsubscribing from my part. After some debugging i noticed that `onDestroy` is being called, but something is not getting destroyed. I have Singleton class that's extending Application class, meaning it does get created only when application starts. But it's `onCreate` method gets called only first time after the app was installed @greeble31

Comment: You're losing me a little bit, @stefan-0905... if `onDestroy()` is being called, then Android has fulfilled its contract regarding `stopwithtask`. If you're not cleaning something up in `onDestroy()`, that's on you... If you are counting on Pusher (whatever that is) to disconnect from the server when the application is _preemptively terminated by the OS, without you executing any further code_, then yes, that will probably happen, if a TCP RST is all you need on the server, but you really shouldn't rely on Android to terminate your app on any particular timetable.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that `onDestroy` is being called after I posted question. That's on me, I thought because everything works fine when i don't start service, it's because service hasn't stopped as I had similar problem in the past.